# Flexbox: Removing blank space after applying media query

Tags: css, flexbox, media-queries, margin, spacing

Do you know why, when I resize my browser down and the flex direction is changed to columns, that my images and text no longer sits in the middle and looks left aligned? There's a huge space on the right hand side and I want the content to always sit in the center no matter what size the browser is. I used the obvious tricks like left-align and center etc, but the space remains.

Code below:

HTML:

```
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="products">
                <div class="product product-1">
                    <img src="images/product-1.jpg">
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta fugit ad in dolores 
                        veniam hic cupiditate aliquam perferendis velit odit.
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="product product-1">
                    <img src="images/product-2.jpg">
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta fugit ad in dolores
                        veniam hic cupiditate aliquam perferendis velit odit.
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="product product-1">
                    <img src="images/product-3.jpg">
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta fugit ad in dolores
                        veniam hic cupiditate aliquam perferendis velit odit.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 400px;
}

.products {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.product-1 {
    width: 33%;
    margin: 0 0.50em;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .products {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .product-1 {
        width: 100%;
    }

    p {
        width: 75%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use flexbox in your `product-1` to center items

```
.product-1 {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```css
.container {
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 400px;
}

.products {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.product-1 {
    width: 33%;
    margin: 0 0.50em;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .products {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .product-1 {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
    }

    p {
        width: 75%;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="products">
                <div class="product product-1">
                    <img src="images/product-1.jpg">
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta fugit ad in dolores 
                        veniam hic cupiditate aliquam perferendis velit odit.
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="product product-1">
                    <img src="images/product-2.jpg">
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta fugit ad in dolores
                        veniam hic cupiditate aliquam perferendis velit odit.
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="product product-1">
                    <img src="images/product-3.jpg">
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta fugit ad in dolores
                        veniam hic cupiditate aliquam perferendis velit odit.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: OMG that works! Thank you!! So simple (facepalm lol)